# Duplicating a record with different ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

An application I am working on invokes a SP like this:

```
exec CreateChildRecord @ParentID = 123, @ChildID = 124
```

The SP needs to copy all fields except the ID from the parent record into the child record. The child record may or may not currently exist.

What I need is something like the below:

```
UPDATE [Table] AS [Table1] SET (data1, data2) = (
   SELECT [Table2].[data1], [Table2].[data2] 
      FROM [Table] AS [Table2] 
      WHERE [Table2.ID] = @ParentID)
   WHERE [Table1].[ID] = @ChildID
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
INSERT INTO [TABLE] (id, data1, data2) 
   (SELECT @ChildID, data1, data2 
      FROM [TABLE] 
      WHERE id = @ParentID)
```

I've tried various combinations of the above to no effect. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can use `merge` statement:

```
merge [Table] as T
using (
    select @ChildID as ID, data1, data2
    from [Table]
    where ID = @ParentID
) as P on P.ID = T.ID
when matched then
    update set
        data1 = P.data1,
        data2 = P.data2
when not matched then
    insert (ID, data1, data2)
    values (P.ID, P.data1, P.data2);
```

If you cannot use `merge`:

```
if exists (select * from [Table] where ID = @ChildID)
    update c set
        data1 = p.data1, 
        data2 = p.data2
    from [Table] as c cross join [Table] as p
    where c.ID = @ChildID and p.ID = @ParentID
else
    insert into [Table] (ID, data1, data2)
    select @ChildID, data1, data2
    from [Table]
    where ID = @ParentID
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3b63/1)</kbd>**

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks. A note for future readers though - it's WHEN MATCHED THEN and WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN if you're using merge.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of SQL Server you are using (2008+) you can make use of [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

> Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based
>   on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you can
>   synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one
>   table based on differences found in the other table.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07d07/15)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ParentID = @ParentID)

    UPDATE Table2 
    SET
       Table2.data1 = Table1.data1, Table2.data2 = Table1.data2
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Table1.ID = @ParentID

ELSE

   INSERT INTO Table2 (ParentID, data1, data2)
   SELECT @ParentID, Table1.data1, Table1.data2
   FROM Table1
   WHERE Table1.ID = @ParentID
```